# NFS maximum number of simultaneous operations per connection?

Tags: nfs

I heard from Tier 3 vendor support that NFS has some sort of limit (I was told 16) as to the number of concurrent operations that can be executing at the same time.

I apologize that I don't have any more specifics, and some Googling hasn't turned up what I am looking for.

Does this hard limitation of NFS exist, and if so, could someone explain a bit more about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can control the number of instances of nfsd but each instance of nfsd might have multiple operations queued with the kernel.  In Linux and Solaris (as far as I remember) the default has been 8 processes for a long time but there are plenty of circumstances where it makes sense to increase this number.  I haven't heard of any absolute limit to concurrency in NFS as a protocol, however.

Answer (score 3):

There are no connection limits as such, but there are some practical limits imposed by port selection, as outlined in the man page for NFS:

> NFS clients usually communicate with NFS servers via network sockets.
>   Each end of a socket is assigned a port value, which is simply a
>   number between 1 and 65535 that distinguishes socket endpoints at the
>   same IP address. A socket is uniquely defined by a tuple that includes
>   the transport protocol (TCP or UDP) and the port values and IP
>   addresses of both endpoints.
>
> The NFS client can choose any source
>   port value for its sockets, but usually chooses a privileged port. A
>   privileged port is a port value less than 1024. Only a process with
>   root privileges may create a socket with a privileged source port.
>
> The exact range of privileged source ports that can be chosen is set
>   by a pair of sysctls to avoid choosing a well-known port, such as the
>   port used by ssh. This means the number of source ports available for
>   the NFS client, and therefore the number of socket connections that
>   can be used at the same time, is practically limited to only a few
>   hundred.

Comment: What does this means. What if we want a NFS share to serve 6 servers, and each want to have 1k open files ?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably thinking of `sunrpc.tcp_slot_table_entries` which needs to be set before mounting a given filesystem.

Up to RHEL  6.3, this was a static value of 16 which is often pushed up to 128 to remove a bottleneck.  In 6.3, this becomes self tuning and auto-adjusting - see P22 of the following [link](http://www.slideshare.net/sshaaf/red-hat-enterprise-linux-and-nfs:).